# How to force visual studio to check for broken file references at compile time

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dependency-management, assemblies

This question is specifically about [file references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019#file-references)

My project has a reference to library A. Library A has a reference to library B. 
If I don't add a direct reference to library B, the project will compile fine, but then throw a "could not load file or assembly B" exception at runtime when it tries to load library A.

So, how do I force visual studio to check for all broken file references at compile time? Alternatively, is there any other way to find these broken references (a tool, VS extension, etc.)

Here's an example project that reproduces the behavior.
https://github.com/RaikolAmaro/BrokenDependencies

Comment: As far as I know, I’m afraid there isn’t an option to force VS to check for all broken file references at compile time. BTW, I also tested on my side but didn’t get an error as you mentioned above, could you please share me with a simple sample which could reproduce this issue? And I will go to check it.

Comment: That surprises me. I can reproduce it in a work related project I'm working on. I thought what I described would be enough to reproduce it but maybe I'm missing something. I will work on creating a small example and I'll post it here for you.

Comment: @KyleWang I added an example in the main post. You can just download and run the console app.

Comment: Thank you for sharing me with this sample. I could reproduce your issue, and after researching more I’m afraid that there isn’t a way to let VS to check for broken file references at compile time. I recommend you could directly suggest this feature to VS Product team from VS > Help > Send Feedback > Suggest a Feature…

Comment: @KyleWang yeah, I know...  I too reached that conclusion, which is why I made this post in hopes someone might explain why this feature doesn't exist. It seems unacceptable to have to wait for an application to blow up at runtime to be able to find these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a compile-time problem, as, at compile time, all required references were present and accounted for. Otherwise, it wouldn't have compiled in the first place.

It's a runtime problem and Visual Studio doesn't care much about what *you* want to have in the output directory or not. This is why you have total control over which elements you want copied from NuGet packages as well as other projects.  Why? Because you may be using a installer or packaging solution or have some magic assembly resolving code to find your dependencies. You may be relying on plugins or configuration based dependency injection. Too many things which will thwart a scan like this.

There is another problem. While an assembly may depend on a certain other assembly, your code may not require it. It that's she case, if your code never loads a codepath that requires this other assembly, then you don't need it in your output directory to run.

There are tools that scan all the codepaths in your projects, the assemblies they depend on and so forth. These can be used to see whether you have all the required binaries to run the code.

- http://www.dependencywalker.com/

There is problem with these tools. The same problems mentioned above. If you use dependency injection through configuration or convention (e.g. based on reflection) or do your own reflection, or depend on the `dynamic` keyword, then these tools may not be able to find all codepaths you depend on and may require some configuration or in-source annotation to figure that out while scanning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jessehouwing. This kind of explanation is what I was looking for, so I will accept this answer. That said, I don't totally agree that the reasons you stated are enough for the IDE to completely ignore a problem like this. At least it could show a suggestion letting the developer know the application might blow up at runtime, as it does for other kinds of code smells. The developer then could decide to ignore the suggestion or fix it. The current behavior seems odd to me.

Comment: For many project it will likely always show the warning, depending on your references... And it is a computationally expensive operation, especially when Visual studio was originally built. It is an interesting case and may be a nice extension or msbuild task.